# Student-Subject Relationship on U.W.P. Application

Tags: uwp

This is my learning assignment. I have Student table and Subject table with a bridge table of Student-Subject. I want to show this on UWP app, like if student is selected than related subject will be shown.

On the main page there will be list of all Students in the database. On click of any Student, a new form will be opened and it's Subjects are shown.

Is there any good article or any related article that will help me to accomplish this? Please show me the links and code samples.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to make a UWP, but you did not know where to start. Then, let's [start with Windows 10 apps](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/get-started/) document.

> I have Student table and Subject table with a bridge table of Student-Subject.

You have several tables to show in your UWP app. So, you could choose local database (e.g, sqlite) or SQL Server database. You could read [Data Access](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/data-access/) to know more detailed information.

> I want to show this on UWP app, like if student is selected than related subject will be shown.

This involves the use of some controls. For example, [Lists controls](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/design/controls-and-patterns/lists).

If you want to develop a fully functional application. I suggest that you need to read more UWP MSDN documentations.

There're many code sample on github: https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples

You could download these samples and learn to develop your own UWP app.